# Circular dependency detected while autoloading constant UserHelper

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I know that there are many questions covering the same, but I couldn't find a satisfactory answer.
Here are my questions:
1) What is the meaning of this problem?
2) How do I fix this?
This is what I am getting:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
# Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
# For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
protect_from_forgery with: :null_session
end
```

I cannot find anything called as UserHelper. Though there is something called as UsersHelper.
UsersHelper is in a file named users_helper.rb inside the directory helpers.
These are the contents of users_helper.rb:

```
module UsersHelper
end
```

This might throw some light:
I am getting the following written right at the top:
RuntimeError in StaticPagesController#home

Comment: can you show the code for UserHelper ?

Comment: I have added its description.

Answer (score 0):

I think

```
module UsersHelper
end
```

should be

```
module UserHelper
end
```

Comment: RuntimeError in StaticPagesController#home
---->This is a part of the error